# Accessing Iframe content using jquery on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using an hidden Iframe and get the response back. The following code works fine on Firefox but breaks on IE. It fails on getting the response back.

```
Line....
var content = $j(this).contents().find("body:last").text();
```

Any help/suggestion is deeply appreciated.
Thanks.

```
$j('#uploadForm').submit(function(e) {

        var jThis = $j('#uploadForm');
        var strName = ("uploader" + (new Date()).getTime());
        var jFrame = $j("<iframe id=\"" + strName + "\" name=\"" + strName + "\" src=\"about:blank\" />");
        jFrame.css("display", "none");

        jThis
                .attr("method", "post")
                .attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data")
                .attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data")
                .attr("target", strName)
                ;

        $j("body:first").append(jFrame);

        jFrame.load(function(objEvent) {
            var content = $j(this).contents().find("body:last").text();
            alert(content);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JQuery has a more specific method to abstract away the differences in IFRAME implementation. I'm also not sure if the JQuery methods can be called on DOM elements in a document (your IFRAME) that doesn't itself have a reference to JQuery. So, I'd try something like this:

```
    var d = $j(this);
if(d.body) {
    return d.body.innerHTML;
    }
else if(d.innerHTML) {
    return d.innerHTML;
    }
else {
    return 'Frame has no body';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jFrame.load(function(objEvent) {
    var content = $(this.contentWindow.document.body).html();
    alert(content);
});
```